# fuse : invalid argument. when mounting

Tags: linux, web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to mount a drive of ec2 instance of amazon web server on my virtual linux machine using sshfs.
The command I used is as below :

```
sameeksha@technician:~$ sudo sshfs -i $HOME/Downloads/amazonkey.pem ec2-user@54.255.172.22:/var/www $HOME/Documents
```

and the error that I get is :

```
fuse: invalid argument `/home/sameeksha/Documents'
```

I have tried to find the problem but I could only find this error occuring when using fuse. But I am not even using fuse here. Using the same command I was able to mount to the drive to my system. But this time strangely it is throwing this error.

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem (also using an ec2 instance) and I found the answer here: https://www.chrisnewland.com/solved-sshfs-with-private-key-what-is-the-syntax-262

What sshfs takes as parameters is different than ssh. What you need is:

```
sudo sshfs -o IdentityFile=$HOME/Downloads/amazonkey.pem ec2-user@54.255.172.22:/var/www $HOME/Documents
```